# When a creature changes form is its melded equipment still burdensome?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores, polymorph, encumbrance

My human PC has been forced to assume magically the form of a typical [squirrel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/squirrel), and his gear has melded into this new form. Does this melded equipment still have weight? If it does still have weight, should that weight be added to squirrel-me's body weight, or should squirrel-me be considered carrying that gear, probably making it so squirrel-me pretty much can't move?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I suspect that this really good question is clouded by your own overspeculation. May I or can you simplify this so that, then, perhaps, you can include the additional information in your own answer?

Comment: Im just sitting down to eat, so I will try to correct it after. In the mean time if you wish to take a crack at it then feel free.

Comment: That gets to the heart of the question I guess, thanks

Comment: You're, of course, more than welcome to rollback or edit it further. I just really like questions like this where it's obvious the designers *either*  didn't care *or* didn't playtest. (Because, really, going from human form encumbered by a 1-ton statue into squirrel form *just to see what happened to the statue* would be among the first things *I* would do at the table.)

Comment: I feel that todays manuals dont need to be restrictive on space, and I find pathfinder to be fairly bad about trying to save space by frequently referring you to another spell or something. Makes it really hard sometimes when the rules are distributed in so many places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [your own question from 2015](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64999/druids-wild-shape-and-armor-check-penalties)?

Comment: That question was about the armor check, and doesnt answer the weight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the answer to [your own question from 2015](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64999/druids-wild-shape-and-armor-check-penalties) (Thanks Mike Q) [Original source](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9tl1)

> If you were in medium or heavy load from encumbrance before transforming, you continue to take those penalties in your melded form. Otherwise, **ignore the weight of melded items** and calculate your encumbrance in your polymorphed form entirely based on non-melded items.

and

> ...if you gain no benefit from the melded armor, you still count as wearing an armor of that type, but you do not suffer its armor check penalty, movement speed reduction, or arcane spell failure chance. If you do gain any benefits (as with the wild property), then you do suffer the armor check penalty, movement speed reduction, and arcane spell failure chance.

So only if you **gain a bonus from having the equipment melded** do you count the weight. One additional note from [Transmutation- Polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/transmutation):

> If your new form does not cause your equipment to meld into your form, the equipment resizes to match your new size.

So any weighted equipment would be a fraction of the weight as well.

Comment: I know more about pathfinder now than I did then. It would not be the first time I made an assumption about something only to have it prove, such as with heighten spell. Been using that wrong since 3.5. Also, I did forget about some aspects of my question and the answers, it was more than a year ago.

Comment: @Fering No worries, I do feel like this is a unique question, but I also feel that the FAQ *does* cover the points in this question as well. If I missed anything let me know and I'll look into it.