# When wildshaping, does the melded gear count against your carry capacity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, wild-shape, encumbrance

When wildshaping as per the druid class ability, does the melded gear count against your carry capacity? e.g. Does a lvl 12 druid with 10 str have the ability to fly as a bat whose str would be 6, whilst still carrying a a medium load, load limit being 66 lbs for medium load as human and 60 lbs for a heavy load as a bat.

Comment: Hey @Ayporos, welcome to the site. We found this question be really similar to [another here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92826/when-a-creature-changes-form-is-its-melded-equipment-still-burdensome) on the site and flagged it as a duplicate. If you find the answers on that other question to be unrelated to yours, let us know either here or there through comments and we will reopen this question once the problem is clarified.